# Contact.CleanStatus missing on developer edition?

Tags: standard-objects, unmanaged-package

unpackaged/objects/Contact.object(111,13):Could not resolve standard field's name.

At line # 111

```
<fields>
    <fullName>CleanStatus</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
```

I am getting following error , what could be issue?

Does that mean "CleanStatus" is no longer available?

Comment: Suggest you examine line 111 of the Contact.object file to identify the standard Contact field name that the problem is with and add that to your question.

Comment: Does the field is deprecated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume the problem is that the org that the Contact.object metadata was extracted from had a feature turned on (probably [Data.com Clean](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/data_dot_com_clean_impl_guide.pdf)) that a typically developer edition org does not have turned on.

Manually deleting the field from the Contact.object metadata is the simplest solution assuming you have no need to configure the field in your application.

Comment: definitely Data.com Clean

Answer (score 0):

While this is caused by Data.com Clean, it's not possible to delete the field as it's a standard object. To remove it, switch to Salesforce Classic, go to Setup, and search for Clean. Finally click the button for Disable Clean.